# MacBook Pro Retina (13-inch, 2015) keyboard and trackpad unresponsive

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad

As in the title. I can only work with mouse and keyboard via USB/BT. Built-in keyboard and trackpad are unresponsive during the boot, login screen nor in OS. Tried: SMC, PRAM reset, safe boot, 3rd party service.

**Surprisingly that tricked worked 2 times in a row: [Remove Existing Wi-Fi Preferences in macOS Sierra](http://osxdaily.com/2016/09/22/fix-wi-fi-problems-macos-sierra/)**

I have no clue - nothing was spilled onto it, it just stopped working and becomes responsive very rarely (apart from the trick described above). I want to avoid keyboard/trackpad/board replacement.

Comment: 3rd party service?  Do you mean you took it to a repair shop?  What did they say?  Have you taken it into Apple?

Comment: They (repair shop) have no clue as well. After measuring signals, voltage, checking connectors etc. they say it looks ok, they are not capable to identify the root cause and advised to bring the mac to Apple. However - my warranty period is over and this option is a last resort.

After all tries, I thought this was a hardware issue but the trick with wireless confused me. Why it works or may it be a coincidence? How can I investigate it further?

Comment: Did the repair shop try a *different* keyboard assembly?  The reason I say that is because the keyboard and trackpad are connected to the USB bus so they are in fact USB devices.

Answer (score -2):

It seems the trackpad cable is a potential cause, due to it rubbing on the back cover as demonstrated in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPFCIE0U1ew&t=26s

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.